# 404 page going to listing entry template only in first segment

Tags: templates, 404

I can only trigger the 404 template for anything more than two segments, for example, if this is bad link I see 404 page: `site.com/wrong/link`

When just accessing one segment like this for example, `site.com/wrong` page displays my listing entry template outputting same entry.

Here's template...maybe something on there or route that isn't set up correctly?

```
{embed="layouts/index"}

{exp:stash:set parse_tags="yes"}
        {stash:content}
            <div id="subpage-container" class="content">
                <table class="Subsection-Image-Table" style="background-image: url('/assets/images/header-background.jpg');">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            <!--
                                <table width="100%">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="width: 50%;" width="50%">
                                                <h1>Personal Checking</h1>
                                                <p>This outer table (with a green outline in cms) is a table with class "<em>Subsection-Image-Table</em>". To change the image of a page with this table, select the table, right click, choose "Table Properties" and choose an image from the background image select box.</p>
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="50%">&nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                -->
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <table class="Subsection-Table">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <h1><a href="{homepage}">Blog</a></h1>
                                <div class="row">

                                        {embed="embeds/_sidebar"}

                                    <div class="col-md-9 entry-listing">
                                        {exp:channel:entries channel="blog_entry" orderby="date" limit="1"}
                                            <div class="col-right">
                                                <ul class="breadcrumbs">
                                                    <li><a href="{homepage}">Blog Home</a></li> 
                                                    <li>{title}</li>
                                                </ul>
                                                <article class="text-area">
                                                    <h1>{title}</h1>
                                                    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
                                                        {blog_entry_images}
                                                            <div>
                                                                <img class="blog-image" src="{blog_entry_images:image}" alt="{alt}" style="margin-bottom:0;"/>
                                                                {if blog_entry_images:caption}<p class="blog-caption">{blog_entry_images:caption}</p>{/if}
                                                            </div>
                                                        {/blog_entry_images}
                                                    </div>
                                                    <span class="posted">Published on {entry_date format='%M %j, %Y'}</span>
                                                    {embed="embeds/_sharing_icons"}
                                                    {blog_entry_blocks}
                                                        {vimeo_embed}
                                                        <div class="videoWrapper">
                                                            {embed}
                                                        </div>
                                                        {/vimeo_embed}

                                                        {block_content}
                                                            {content}
                                                        {/block_content}
                                                    {/blog_entry_blocks}
                                                </article>
                                            </div>
                                        {/exp:channel:entries}  
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <table class="Subsection-Image-Table" style="background-image: url('/assets/images/footer-background.jpg');">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <!--
                                <table width="100%">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width="50%">
                                                <h2><a id="Smart-Checking"></a>Heading 2</h2>
                                                <p>A table with the class "Subsection-Image-Table" can be used throughout the site in different locations. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam magna purus, dapibus vel luctus id, efficitur sed nibh. Pellentesque sit amet elit imperdiet, pharetra ipsum non, eleifend metus.</p>
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="50%">&nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                -->
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div><!--/subpage-container-->

        {/stash:content}

{/exp:stash:set}
```

Here's my route setup:
[image]

Comment: You'll need to provide some information about what your template / routes actually look like - your posting here indicates that whatever is in 'layouts/index' is part of your template output - not just this stash tag.  Likewise if you are using Template Routes you need to let us know what the route settings actually are.  Based on what you are reporting, I'd think it most likely that there is something wrong with your template route settings rather than being template based.

Comment: I added a screenshot above.

Comment: Probably worth noting: I'm using Structure addon.

Answer (score 0):

Still not entirely sure from your question what you are trying to do, or how the template excerpt helps, but just for clarification, the template route in the screen grab will capture any URL that happens to begin `/blog/something` - regardless of whatever follows it (provided the second term matches the alpha_dash character list).

Unless you have some other route set up, there appears to be no way that you can get a 404 to display for any URL that happens to begin `/blog/something`as the template route will grab these and send them to your `blog-entry` template.

Maybe you should think about changing the template route status for **Segments Required?** to yes - this will not change the route behaviour for `/blog/something` but will not intercept urls with more terms (so `/blog/something/else` wouldn't be captured by the route if you change the segments required flag.

HTH

Comment: I've narrowed down to it being an issue relating to Stash addon. I haven't resolved per dev's documentation and still working on it. I'll be sure to provide update when I find solution.